# Get part of string that matches with another string

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a VBA Macro for Excel and I need to get the part of a file path that matches with a specific string.

I mean, I have a `Variant` called `FileInfo` that contains the path of the Workbook that I am using at that moment (inside a For), for example, Variant may look like:

```
C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\SVN-Folder\trunk\G\INC20825\Estimación Temporal_v01r00.xlsx
```

I want to make a function that returns only the part of the path that matches with `"INC*"` and if the path doesn't have that match, return null.

So the function in this case may return: `INC20825`

I tried with this but did not work

```
'This function returns the INC folder where is contained
Function INCFolder(FileInfo As Variant)
Dim i As Integer

If FileInfo Like "INC*" Then
    i = InStr(FileInfo, "INC")
    INCFolder = Mid(FileInfo, i, 8)
Else
    INCFolder = Null
End If

End Function
```

**EDIT with partial solution:**
I made it working to get the 8 characters of `INC*` with the following code:

```
'This function returns the INC folder where is contained
Function INCFolder(FileInfo As Variant)
Dim i As Integer

i = InStr(FileInfo, "INC")

If i = 0 Then
    INCFolder = Null
Else
    INCFolder = Mid(FileInfo, i, 8)
End If

End Function
```

Problems will come when INC is bigger or smaller than 8

Comment: Will the **`INC`** part in the path always have 8 characters? I would make it more dynamic

Comment: Yes, it may not have 8 characters but I don't know how to make it more dynamic

Comment: @Pablo.x see my answer below, it will give you flexibilty to be more dynamic and be flexible with any number of characters

Comment: Yes, just realized, worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Split` to seperate your `\` from your full path to `PathArr` array elements, and then loop through `PathArr` elements and look for **"*INC*"**.

The code below will give you flexibility with the number of characters you have for "***INC***".

***Code***

```
Option Explicit        

Sub test()

Const FullName = "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\SVN-Folder\trunk\G\INC20825\Estimación Temporal_v01r00.xlsx"
Dim INCSection As String

INCSection = INCFolder(FullName)

End Sub
```

---

```
Function INCFolder(FileInfo As Variant) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim PathArr As Variant

    If FileInfo Like "*INC*" Then
        PathArr = Split(FileInfo, "\") ' split folders to array

        For i = 0 To UBound(PathArr) ' loop through array and look for "*INC*"
            If PathArr(i) Like "*INC*" Then
                INCFolder = PathArr(i)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        INCFolder = "Error!"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks a lot for your answer, this is what I was trying.

Comment: That's exactly what I was suggesting

Comment: Yes, totally true :D

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more `*` in the `Like`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const pathName = "C:\Folder\trunk\G\INC20825\Estimación Temporal_v01r00.xlsx"


Function INCFolder(FileInfo As Variant)
    Dim i As Long

    If FileInfo Like "*INC*" Then
        i = InStr(FileInfo, "INC")
        INCFolder = Mid(FileInfo, i, 8)
    Else
        INCFolder = False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: This works too, I've just edited my question because I "found" a way to make it work for 8 characters

Answer (score 1):

Just the alternate way to get the result

```
Function INCFolder(FileInfo As Variant)
    If FileInfo Like "*INC*" Then
        INCFolder = Mid(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Mid(FileInfo, InStr(FileInfo, "\INC"), Len(FileInfo)), "\", "|", 2), 2, WorksheetFunction.Search("|", WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Mid(FileInfo, InStr(FileInfo, "\INC"), Len(FileInfo)), "\", "|", 2)) - 2)
    Else
        INCFolder = Null
    End If
End Function
```